# Hoe to split data of one column in multiple columns on the basis of a condition

Tags: postgresql

I have one table having data

```
Category.                            New data
Cost of equipment.                    23
Price of equipments.                  45
Cost of M&C.                          13
Price of M&C.                         12
```

And one another table having

```
Category
Equipments
M&C
```

Now i want data as below

```
Category                 Cost                   Price
Equipment                 23                    45
M&C                       13                    12
```

Can you please help me in solving this

Comment: Please share what code you have tried to write in the question details.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. A better approach is to change your table design.

Note that while joining I had to use `RTRIM` to remove `s` from equipments. I am not aware of any other variations in your data which might not match between the two tables. Please change the join conditions appropriately ( or use a `REGEXP` match  instead of `ILIKE` if they don't )

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/264b2/19)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (Category varchar(19), New_data int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (Category, New_data)
VALUES
    ('Cost of equipment', 23),
    ('Price of equipments', 45),
    ('Cost of M&C', 13),
    ('Price of M&C', 12)
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    (Category varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (Category)
VALUES
    ('Equipments'),
    ('M&C')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH t1
AS (
    SELECT b.category
        ,a.new_data
    FROM TABLE1 a
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.Category ILIKE '%cost%' || RTRIM(b.Category, 's') || '%'
    )
    ,t2
AS (
    SELECT c.category
        ,a.new_data
    FROM TABLE1 a
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 c ON a.Category ILIKE '%price%' || RTRIM(c.Category, 's') || '%'
    )
SELECT t1.category
    ,t1.new_data AS cost
    ,t2.new_data AS price
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.category = t2.category
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/264b2/19/0)**:

```
|   category | cost | price |
|------------|------|-------|
| Equipments |   23 |    45 |
|        M&C |   13 |    12 |
```